# Visualise intersection of two images using a shader

Tags: qt, qml, shader, opengl-es-2.0, qtquick2

I'm trying to visualise the intersection of two images using a shader. Here are the images:

[image: shadow1] [image: shadow2]

I have the foundation set up, using the default fragment shader code as shown [here](https://qmlbook.github.io/ch10-shaders/shaders.html#shader-elements):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Finding image intersection with a shader"
    visible: true

    Column {
        Row {
            Column {
                Image {
                    id: shadow1
                    source: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzpV8.png"
                }
                Label {
                    text: "shadow1"
                }
            }

            Column {
                Image {
                    id: shadow2
                    source: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9bxx.png"
                }
                Label {
                    text: "shadow2"
                }
            }

            Column {
                Item {
                    width: 100
                    height: 100
                    Image {
                        source: shadow1.source
                    }
                    Image {
                        source: shadow2.source
                    }
                }
                Label {
                    text: "intersection"
                }
            }
        }

        Row {
            Column {
                ShaderEffect {
                    width: shadow1.width
                    height: shadow1.height

                    property var source: shadow1

                    fragmentShader: "
                        varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
                        uniform sampler2D source;
                        uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
                        void main() {
                            gl_FragColor = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0) * qt_Opacity;
                        }"
                }
                Label {
                    text: "shader"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result so far:

[image: screenshot]

How can I take these two images as input and render the resulting intersection?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Finding image intersection with a shader"
    visible: true

    Column {
        Row {
            Column {
                Image {
                    id: shadow1
                    source: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzpV8.png"
                }
                Label {
                    text: "shadow1"
                }
            }

            Column {
                Image {
                    id: shadow2
                    source: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9bxx.png"
                }
                Label {
                    text: "shadow2"
                }
            }

            Column {
                Item {
                    width: 100
                    height: 100
                    Image {
                        source: shadow1.source
                    }
                    Image {
                        source: shadow2.source
                    }
                }
                Label {
                    text: "intersection"
                }
            }
        }

        Row {
            Column {
                ShaderEffect {
                    width: shadow1.width
                    height: shadow1.height

                    property var source1: shadow1
                    property var source2: shadow2

                    fragmentShader: "
                        varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
                        uniform sampler2D source1;
                        uniform sampler2D source2;
                        uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
                        void main() {
                            vec4 colour1 = texture2D(source1, qt_TexCoord0);
                            vec4 colour2 = texture2D(source2, qt_TexCoord0);
                            if (colour1.a > 0.0 && colour2.a > 0.0) {
                                // There is an intersection here; mark it.
                                gl_FragColor = vec4(0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
                            } else {
                                // There's no intersection here; make this pixel transparent.
                                gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                            }
                        }"
                }
                Label {
                    text: "shader"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll briefly explain the additions I made:

```
uniform sampler2D source1;
uniform sampler2D source2;
```

These two lines declare the input images. `sampler2D` refers to Qt Quick's `Image` type.

```
    vec4 colour1 = texture2D(source1, qt_TexCoord0);
    vec4 colour2 = texture2D(source2, qt_TexCoord0);
```

These two lines declare two `vec4` variables to store the colour for each pixel at this coordinate (`qt_TextCoord0`).

```
    if (colour1.a > 0.0 && colour2.a > 0.0) {
        // There is an intersection here; mark it.
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    } else {
        // There's no intersection here; make this pixel transparent.
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
```

The if statements check the alpha values of each pixel. If they're both non-zero, a semi-transparent red pixel will be drawn.

The result:

[image: screenshot]